# How to Let only one view get the gesture at a time?

Tags: ios, uikit, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have multiple imageViews that I drag around in my app.
I have added a pangesture to each imageView.

Is there a way by which I can cancel gestures on other images while I am dragging one ?

I am thinking of setting some instance-var being set to image being dragged.
say: imageViewBeingDragged and check if recognizer's view matches this one and set this view on began state and set to nil when gestures state is ended.

If there is a simpler way then please tell because I feel what I am thinking might be unnecessarily complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the `exclusiveTouch` property of a UIView not sufficient for you? I'm not sure how that works in combination with `UIGestureRecognizers`.